# Retornar informações de uma String

Tags: java, string, concatenação-de-string

Estou tentando retornar as informações de uma String.

O que eu preciso é passar uma String parâmetro e retornar as informações que esta nos lugares indicados.

Ex.:

```
String FraseParametro = "<R1> casou com <R2>, e traiu ela com <R3>.";

String Frase = "João Pedro casou com Maria, e traiu ela com Joaquina Fofa.";

retorno = {{"<R1>","João Pedro"},{"<R2>", "Maria"}, {"<R3>", "Joaquina Fofa"}}
```

Como posso fazer isso?

O meu problema é que são várias frases diferente e a posição dos `<R >` são diferentes.

Comment: Não sei se isso pode te ajudar, mas o <R1> está entre o inicio da string e a palavra casou. O <R2> está entre com e a vírgula e o <R3> está entre o com e o ponto final.

Não é bem uma resposta, mas acredito que possa te guiar ;)

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma muito simples de fazer isso é com o replace.

```
String troca[][] = {{"<R1>","João Pedro"},{"<R2>", "Maria"}, {"<R3>", "Joaquina Fofa"}};
String FraseParametro = "<R1> casou com <R2>, e traiu ela com <R3>.";
System.out.println(FraseParametro);
for(int i = 0;i<troca.length;i++)
    FraseParametro = FraseParametro.replace(troca[i][0], troca[i][1]);
System.out.println(FraseParametro);
```

Tente fazer ao contrario substituir o que voce tem por um marcador.
Assim só sobrara o que desejas.

```
String FraseParametro[] = {"casou com",", e traiu ela com"};
String Frase = "João Pedro casou com Maria, e traiu ela com Joaquina Fofa.";
for(int i = 0;i<FraseParametro.length;i++)
    Frase = Frase.replace(FraseParametro[i],";");

System.out.println(Frase);

String[] teste = Frase.split(";");
for(int i = 0;i<teste.length;i++)
    System.out.printf("\nIndice %s - Valor: %s",i,teste[i].trim());
```

Comment: Opa, mas o que eu quero é ao contrario.
A "FraseParametro" eu sei que nesse formado, mas não sei qual é o valor que esta nos "<R >".
Em vez de trocar eu quer recuperar o valor que esta no lugar do "<R >".

Comment: Complementei a questão, de uma olhada se assim lhe atende

Comment: Opa.. valeu, acho q ja me ajuda!!

Comment: Blz, só não esqueça de colocar como resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Possível solução:

```
public class App {

private List<String> keys;
private String fraseParametro;
private String frase;
private Map<String, String> map;

public App() {
    keys = new ArrayList<>();
    map = new HashMap<>();
}

public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String fraseParametro = "<R1> casou com <R2>, e traiu ela com <R3>.";

    String frase = "João Pedro casou com Maria, e traiu ela com Joaquina Fofa.";

    App app = new App();
    app.addKey("<R3>");
    app.addKey("<R1>");
    app.addKey("<R2>");

    app.setFrase(frase);
    app.setFraseParametro(fraseParametro);
    app.createPairKeyValue();
    Map<String, String> keyValue = app.getMap();
    System.out.printf("Frase Parâmetro: %s\n", app.getFraseParametro());
    System.out.printf("Frase: %s\n", app.getFrase());
    for (String key : keyValue.keySet()) {
        System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", key, keyValue.get(key));
    }

}

public void createPairKeyValue() {
    Collections.sort(keys);

    String findingSubstitues = frase;
    for (String key : keys) {
        String replacement = findValue(findingSubstitues, key);
        if (replacement != null) {
            map.put(key, replacement);
            findingSubstitues = findingSubstitues.replaceAll(replacement, key);
        }
    }
}

public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    return this.map;
}

private String findValue(String phrase, String key) {
    List<String> phraseWithKeys = getWords(fraseParametro);
    List<String> phraseWithoutKeys = getWords(phrase);
    int index = phraseWithKeys.indexOf(key);

    if (index == -1) {
        return null;
    }

    String replacement = phraseWithoutKeys.get(index);

    for (int i = index+1; i < phraseWithoutKeys.size(); ++i) {
        if (((index+1) == phraseWithKeys.size()) || !phraseWithoutKeys.get(i).equals(phraseWithKeys.get(index+1))) {
            replacement += " " + phraseWithoutKeys.get(i);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return replacement;
}

public void addKey(String key) {
    keys.add(key);
}

public void setFraseParametro(String fraseParametro) {
    this.fraseParametro = fraseParametro;
}

public void setFrase(String frase) {
    this.frase = frase;
}

public List<String> getWords(String phrase) {
    String[] words = phrase.split(" |,|\\.");
    return Arrays.asList(words);
}

public String getFraseParametro() {
    return fraseParametro;
}

public String getFrase() {
    return frase;
}
```

}